# Problem installing JDT in Eclipse on linux

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse on Fedora Core 14 using `yum install eclipse-platform`. I ran eclipse and tried to install the java development tools, but then this error came up:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. 
Software being installed: 
Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.6.2.r362_v20101117-0800-7z8XFW6FLFlmjJcvz03jyeFBLS_F (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101117-0800-7z8XFW6FLFlmjJcvz03jyeFBLS_F) 
Software currently installed: 
Eclipse Platform 3.6.1 (Eclipse Platform 3.6.1) 
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Eclipse IDE UI 3.6.1.M20100825-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.6.1.M20100825-0800) 
Eclipse IDE UI 3.6.0.I20100601-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.6.0.I20100601-0800) 
Eclipse IDE UI 3.6.2.M20101201-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.6.2.M20101201-0800) 
Cannot satisfy dependency: 
From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1 (Eclipse Platform 3.6.1) 
To: org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.6.1.M20100825-0800] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: 
From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.6.2.r362_v20101117-0800-7z8XFW6FLFlmjJcvz03jyeFBLS_F (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 
    3.6.2.r362_v20101117-0800-7z8XFW6FLFlmjJcvz03jyeFBLS_F) 
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.2 
Cannot satisfy dependency: 
From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 
    3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi) 
To: org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.6.2.M20101201-0800]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you installed the IDE using yum and then went inside the IDE to install the latest java development tools. If you install Eclipse from the package management system of your linux distribution, then you should install the development tools from this system as well. I'm sure there is an eclipse-jdt package in yum. The dependency is probably from eclipse-jdt to eclipse, which was a concious decision as the reverse is optional.

There are two solutions, either stick to the packages from your IDE or download the archive from the eclipse website. The first option will provide a stable environment where all the pieces work together nicely. The second will give you the latest (stable) version of everything and you will have less trouble with conflicts like this when you add/install components from inside of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to just download Eclipse from the website and unzip it in your home folder. I've had similar conflicts in the past, and not using the packages from the OS in this case just helped me.

I know this is not the answer that you are looking for, but I consider a valid alternative, if what you want is just to have an IDE installed on your system.